How to show $R>0$ from $\partial_t R =\Delta R + R(R-r)$ and $R\ge0$?
Picture below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this).  I'm confused about the red line part. In this paper, the author consider the normalized Ricci flow
$$
\partial_t g_{ij} = (r-R) g_{ij} \tag{1}
$$
where $r$ is the average value of $R$.
First, the minimum value of $R$ is constant.
Second, I only know  the strong maximum principle of heat equation,  it means that "if solution attains its minimum at an interior point, then it is constant"
Since the minimum value of $R$ is constant, the minimum of $R$ must be attained interior. Therefore, $R$ must be constant. Then, the rest of the proof is superfluous.
Besides, I can't see $R>0$ from the strong maximum principle. I feel  there's something wrong in my understanding of strong maximum principle.




What is $r$? ${}{}{}{}{}$

@ArcticChar  Sorry, $r$  is the average value of $R$.  Namely, $r=\int R d\mu /\int d\mu$. In fact, $r$ is a constant under normalized Ricci flow.

The maximum principle you stated is for heat-type equations (linear PDEs with $c=0$, see Evans, PDEs, p389).
Here we deal with non linear PDEs (the zero order term is quadratic) and the result we should use can be found for example in Topping, Lecture notes on Ricci flow, p44 (the strong version is only stated in Rmk 3.1.3). It essentially says that we can compare  the minimum of the solution of the PDE at time $t$ with the solution of the associated ODE (just leaving the zero order terms) at time t, with initial datum the minimum of the initial datum of the PDE.
Since in this case we are interested in taking $R=0$ as minimum of the initial datum and the solution of the ODE would be constantly $0$, the statement looks the same as the linear one. The (nonlinear version of the) strong maximum principle also tells you that if $R\geq0$ at $t=0$ and $R=0$ somewhere for $t=0$, then $R=0$ everywhere, and this is what Hamilton uses.
However you cannot say that "if the solution attains its minimum at an interior point, then it is constant". The correct statement instead is "if the solution attains the value of the solution of the corresponding ODE at an interior point then it must be constant in space and equal to the ODE solution".
I suggest you in this case to study the associated ODE (it might be illuminating, in particular you can see the difference between $r<0$, $r=0$ and $r>0$). You can see for instance that when $r>0$ and $0<\phi(0)<r$, the ODE solution decreases, and in particular having that the minimum of $R$ is constant does not allow to conclude that it must be constant.

I accept this conclusion from a different way. For some heat type equations,  when  $t=0$,  if $R\ge 0$ and $R\not\equiv 0$, then, for $t>0$ there is $R>0$.  Seemly, Chow and Knopf say it in The Ricci flow: An introduction, although they didn't write it down as a theorem.

Maybe I had misunderstood your question. I thought that the classical strong maximum principle (e.g. Evans, PDE II edition, p 396) was clear. I tried to explain the difference between the linear and nonlinear cases, in particular to argue why the reasoning "Since the minimum value of  is constant, the minimum of  must be attained interior. Therefore,  must be constant. Then, the rest of the proof is superfluous." cannot be applied.
